# What is the disadvantage of method swizzling in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, method-swizzling

What is the disadvantage of method swizzling in Objective-C?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to maintain, crazy to debug! And it takes some serious skill to write it in the first place!